# Corrupt .drectve at end of def file

Tags: c++, mingw, static-linking, mingw32

I updated my mingw installation, and recently i started to get the errors while building various programms. The error was:

```
Warning: corrupt .drectve at end of def file
```

The problem is that i can not understand where this error is come from!

I have a lot of built static libraries that i assembled usng mingw, is there a way i can somehow find where this error is generated? There is lots of def files of different libraries, but i can't find the `drectve` section in any. The programms seems to work fine, but i'am afraid that this linking error may lead to some runtime errors.

Comment: Have you built and searched the link map?  Or does the build abort because of a 'Warning'?

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN the build doesn't abort, it builds successfully. About map file, i haven't produced it, im gonna try and see.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN i produced the map file, how do i find the corrupted def? In the map file there is no signs about corrupted defs. How do i find the corrupted one??

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN i produced the map using `-Wl,-Map=output.map`

Comment: I was expecting -Map to report about it, possibly in an obtuse way ... and a grep of the map would find it.

Comment: when I googled, just now, for the string "corrupt .drectve" a number of other SO postings were listed, commenting about  incompatible MSVC libs. Check them out.  Sorry I was not much help.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN i checked them out already, i think the problem is somewhere else, all my libs are built with mingw.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN i rechecked with grep, and made make clean, make again. Still no `corrupt` word in map file, and no words like `error`. Maybe i need some other options for the linker, rather then `-Wl,-Map=output.map` in configure.ac?

Comment: I know of no other way to generate a map.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN it seems the programms with this warning sometimes crash!  I ran one in the gdb, and i was getting the output like this http://pastebin.com/Nq9GSHZC  if i don't fix it, i cant continue to work.. i would never use mingw..

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN the segmentation fault occures only if i run the programm under gdb, altought i'm not sure

Comment: OOPS - my comments where I mentioned minGW were incorrect.  cygwin uses dll's, minGW does not.  My bad.  I deleted the incorrect comment.